# How can I contain a file using the NDEF data type for NFC card emulation

Tags: arrays, types, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

In trying to implement some card emulation using NFCPY, I've come across the NDEF data type. I've attached its records along with their comment explanations below.

```
ndef_data_area = bytearray(64 * 16)
ndef_data_area[0] = 0x10 # NDEF mapping version '1.0'
ndef_data_area[1] = 12 # Number of blocks that may be read at once
ndef_data_area[2] = 8 # Number of blocks that may be written at once
ndef_data_area[4] = 63 # Number of blocks available for NDEF data
ndef_data_area[10] = 1 # NDEF read and write operations are allowed
ndef_data_area[14:16] = struct.pack('>H', sum(ndef_data_area[0:14])) # Checksum
```

**My question is, how can I manually encode a file into these records (NDEF fields)?**

I've come across mobile apps that enable the transmission of GPS data, emails, text messages, but I am unsure of how these programs interact with the records of the NDEF data type as they are shown above. As a weaker problem, I tried encoding a string into the NDEF fields, but I am told that only integers are accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So some docs on the Ndef standards are available to read at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/tree/master/docs

Some types of data can be handled by "Well Known" types, some types can be handled as "URI" type, e.g. //, email://

A lot of more custom stuff is handled by Mime Type records e.g. "image/png", "application/vcard", etc